# FindRoot and piecewise

Tags: equation-solving, piecewise

I want to solve numerically for a variable, let's say `x`. The equation that defines `x` has as argument a piecewise function that has its pieces depending on `x` itself. Moreover, some parts of this piecewise function are non-linear solutions of `x`. Let me try to better explain with an example.

The easiest example I could come up with is given below:

```
    a = 1;
b = 0.1;
y = 1 - x[p] - (b + a - 1);
FG[p_?NumericQ] = 
  FindRoot[1 - x + a*Log[1 + x] - x[p] == 0, {x, 0.5}][[1, 2]];
V[p_?NumericQ] := 
 Piecewise[{{p*x[p] + (1 - p)*y, 
    x[p] < 1 + a*Log[b + a] - (b + a - 1) && 
     b*Log[b + a] < y < 1 + b*Log[b + a] - (b + a - 1)}, {p*
      x[p] + (1 - p)*y, 
    x[p] < 1 + a*Log[b + a] - (b + a - 1) && 
     y < b*Log[b + a]}, {p*x[p] + (1 - p)*y, 
    x[p] < 1 + a*Log[b + a] - (b + a - 1) && 
     y >= 1 + 
       b*Log[b + a] - (b + a - 1)}, {p*(1 - FG[p] + 
        a*Log[1 + FG[p]]) + (1 - p)*y, 
    x[p] >= 1 + a*Log[b + a] - (b + a - 1) && 
     b*Log[b + a] < y < 1 + b*Log[b + a] - (b + a - 1)}}, 0]
```

I want to solve:

```
p = 1;

FindRoot[x + a*Log[b + a] + 
  V[p] - (1 + 0.56*(1 - p) + 0.5*p), {x, -.5}]
```

This is not working and I can't figure out way. I have tried to inactivate `FG[p]` and or `V[p]` but it doesn't help. I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: In the definition of `FG`, `x` is used as both a variable (`x`) and as a function (`x[p]`). Also, in this definition, what is `Y`? Should it be `y`?

Comment: Actually the x in FG is a function of p. Sorry for the misunderstand. Also, Y=1, that was a typo, I have just fixed.

Comment: You still have `x` used as both a variable and as a function. You cannot use `FindRoot` to solve for a function.

Comment: Uf, of course not! Thank you very much, Bob Harlon. My problem would be fixed by not having x[p] but x.